# Providing KML data in embedded Google Map, but how to hide the KML to the user

Tags: google-maps, kml

I've embedded google maps several times, only doing basic stuff though.

Now I need to overlay districts over a city. I worked hard to get, parse and adjust all the coordinates for all districts and I don't want others to copy my coordinates.

Can I display the overlays, but prevent users from reading the KML coordinates ? Is there a way to embed them other than having the path visible for everyone in the javascript api block ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a FusionTablesLayer.  You can import your KML into a FusionTable, and prevent it from being downloaded, but display it on a map.  People will be able to look at your coordinates, but it will be difficult (but probably not impossible) to grab them.

Comment: I've created a fusion table, I have it set to "accessible by link", I have the "publish" html code for the map that I want to present embedded in my site. Now how to prevent the coordinates from being downloaded ? In the embed code there's a long identifier for the "query select from". Can this identifier be used to access not only the map but also the referred data (kml coordinates ?)

Comment: As I said in my original answer, people can see your table (using that ID), but if you configure your table to prevent downloads, they won't be able to download the data (but they can "see" it).  You can pay for the ability to protect against them even seeing it [a "Protected" Map Layer](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fusion-tables-protected-map-layer.html)

Comment: ok, in my settings "download of a fusion table" is prohibited now and I tried what a normal user would have access too. I didn't know what you meant by "see" it (data), but now I tried and see that a user only has to double click the kml cell of the districts fusion table, and there he can "see" the raw kml code and so he can immediately copy and paste all coordinates. Repeat that #amountDistricts times and he has copied all my work :( This means for me I have to pay, or am I still missing an option ?